# custom element, custom event handler attributes

Tags: custom-element, custom-events

Built in browser elements have event attributes which execute arbitrary javascript as described below

[image: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers]

**Is there any way to create a custom element with a similar behaving *custom event* handler attribute, and is there a standard pattern for doing so?** Where the {some custom eventType}="{some code}" executes with the correct values in scope and the this binding set correctly.

```
<some-custom-element oncustomevent="alert('worked')" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question is: Do you really want to allow executing code from a string? Because it requires `eval()`

There is nothing wrong with using `eval()` **when you understand the implications**:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

#### Trigger dynamic (string) code:

- from a Custom Element attribute `onevent`
- from a Custom Element setter `onevent`
- from a Custom Event `onevent` detail (see `connectedCallback`)

```js
  function triggerEvent(name, code = "console.warn('No code parameter')") {
    console.log(name, this);
    if (this === window) console.warn('no element scope');
    try {
      if (typeof code === "string") eval(code);
      else console.warn("code is not a string")
    } catch (e) { console.error(e) }
  }
  customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ['onevent'];
    }
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.onclick = () => triggerEvent.call(this, "element Click", "console.log('from element click')");
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      document.addEventListener("onevent", evt => {
        triggerEvent.call(this, "EventListener", evt.detail);
      })
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
      if (name === "onevent") {
        triggerEvent.call(this, "attributeChangedCallback", newValue);
      }
    }
    set onevent(newValue) {
      triggerEvent.call(this, "setter", newValue);
    }
  });

  setTimeout(() => document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("onevent", {
      detail: "console.log('from dispatchEvent detail')"
    })), 2000); //execute after elements listen
```

```html
<my-element onevent="console.log('from element attribute')">click my-element</my-element>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('my-element').onevent='console.log(&quot;from button&quot;)'"
>Call setter</button>
```

JSFiddle playground at: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/ezacw5xL/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had three follow up questions though.

1. The event is currently triggered on attribute change, would there be a standard pattern for executing it on event triggering?

2. Is this a standard way of doing things, or do most people in the community prefer not to use custom event handler attributes like this? note: One thing I didn't realize is that eval is always executed in the current scope. That affected my understanding of the original problem

Comment: The listener in the ``connectedCallback`` listens for events (bubbling up to) ``document``, isn't that what you mean with 'event triggering'? I have never used nor seen this 'pattern' so I presume there is no *standard way*; it is your code, you can do what you want. When publishing components add plenty of documentation and example usages.

Comment: I didn't catch that before, ty for pointing that out to me. Yes that is what I meant by event triggering.